# Display URLS as links(Higlight, blue color, clickable etc) in Django Text Area Field

Tags: django, django-forms, textarea, modelform

I have a site where users can post stuff (mainly links with comments.)

Now when I render the text area filed, the links are being displayed as plain text. They are not clickable, blue links.

I want to render identified urls as links which are clickable.

Don't suggest a language or syntax in which the user has to prepend something to make it a link.

Instead I want an automatic way for links to be clickable. Like how SO and SE and other forums do it.

Comment: what you're looking for is a parser/renderer for a specific type of input format.  Might want to take a look at markdown parsers for django

Comment: @Jason Does Markdown automatically make links clickable without prepending or appending anything to the input?

Comment: It's what this site, github and others use. Check it out

Comment: @Jason Can you give django specific details like which app to use?

Comment: Pick one that's being currently maintained by the latest repository commit or release. Other than that, sorry